# Why does Ulfric think I am a Stormcloak?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

After around 200h of game play I finally decided to join the Legion and take out the racist Ulfric (I am an elf...).

However, after completing [The Jagged Crown](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jagged_Crown_(Quest)) (and being very suspicious of why any of the Stormcloaks weren't attacking me) I started [Message to Whiterun](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Message_to_Whiterun). However, when I go to talk to Ulfric, he completely thinks I am a Stormcloak and the next mission starts as If I were.
What is happening? How can I make clear that I am not a Stormcloak? A polite mail to Ulfric is not possible, so what should I do?

NOTE: this may be the reason of the bug: Long ago I joined the legion (but didn't want to) so I reset the mission with commands. Later, to restart it I also needed to do it with commands, starting [The Jagged Crown](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jagged_Crown_(Quest)) directly.

Additional information: I tried setting the stage of `Message to Whiterun` to different objectives. The best I did was to actually reach Whiterun and talk with the Jarl, but then the general leading the defense doesnt want to further advance the mission. I can't either start the siege of Whiterrun by command lines, I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

I belive you used the wrong Quest ID when you restarted the quest. [The Jagged Crown](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jagged_Crown_(Quest)) can be done by either faction however on the Unoffical Elder Scrolls Page we can see there are 2 different Quest IDs with the same numbered stages (excluding the unknown ones)

- [Stormcloks](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Jagged_Crown_%28Stormcloaks%29#Quest_Stages) = CW02B
- [Imperials](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Jagged_Crown_%28Imperial%29#Quest_Stages) = CW02A

On the Wikia you can also see in Quest ID the 2 different ID, however even if you used the Stormcloaks ID by mistake there is a way to reverse it before the quest complete under the [Optional betrayal - switching sides](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jagged_Crown_%28Quest%29#Optional_betrayal_-_switching_sides) part

> While the Jagged Crown is in the possession of the Dragonborn, they can also decide to travel to the capital city of the opposition to hand over the crown to either General Tullius in Solitude or Jarl Ulfric Stormcloak in Windhelm. The leader of the opposing faction will accept the crown and unceremoniously recognize the Dragonborn as a member of their faction. From there on, the Dragonborn will fight the Civil War for their new allies.

if you have already completed it then you have 3 options.

1. Reload to before the option to betray (if you have the save)
2. reset the mission like you have done previously and redo the command, this time either using the Quest ID for the Imperial's Quest or remembering to betray the Stromcloaks before you finish the quest
3. Ulfric trusts you, this is your chance to kill him in the name of the Imperial Legion! (not sure if he is set as essential though)

Comment: Haha, I love Option 3 but he is an essential character at this point in time...

Comment: @James *"at this point in time"* must mean that at some point he wont which means you can still do the 3rd option right? anyway in real life if you want with the 3rd option you'd probably wait until Ulfric is out in the open, have bandits attack his group and in the confusion slay him with an arrow and claim it came from an archer who escaped (or even produce a dead archer and say you slayed him but was too late for Ulfric)

Comment: I shall say nothing as I was trying to be as spoiler free as possible, even though the game is 3yrs old now :D

Comment: Mmmm but I do  complete the Jagged crown talking to Legate Rikke and then going to Solitude. And actually is Tullius who gives me the next quest! I am pretty sure I did CW02A.

Comment: @AnderBiguri hmmm, the only other thing i can think of is that you resetted the "Join the Legion/Stormclocks", did the stomrclocks one and used console commands to start CW02A bypassing the prerequisite

Comment: I didn't :(. I am 100% sure I didn't do anything for the stormcloacks ever, really. Long time ago I just joined the legion by killing the bandid camp. Then I reseted that. Then I played some lots of hours. Then I tried to start by commands the last step of "joining the legion". As I couldn't (I dont know why), I started "the jagged crown" with the legion part. Talked to Rikke outside the place, got inside, nobody attacked me and took the crown. My marker was leading me to Tullius and so I did. He tells me to go to Whiterun and you know the rest.

Comment: @AnderBiguri is it possible for you to restart that quest at the beginning (stage 1), i would assume at some point during the quest the game would run a script which changes character's perception of you so your would receive negative comments from stormcloack members/allies

Comment: It looks like the game doesnt know that I am with the legion... I dont know if there is a variable somewhere I can set up to tell it. I tried your suggestion, but didnt work. However, I tried seting the stage to 100 (whihc means I already talked to Ulfric) and that worked nice, I got sent back to whiterun. I talk with the Jarl nicely and he tells me to talk with the Imperial guy. Then the imperial guy just doesn't want to follow the conversation and I get stuck there. I tried starting the next quest but doesn't work neither. Any clue?

Comment: @AnderBiguri i would assume when this imperial guy does follow you've tried quitting and starting the game up again, aside from that i'm not sure, i rarely use console commands and i normally follow the stormcloaks (the empire really leaves a sour taste in my mouth with that white-gold concordant)

Comment: Definitely I tried. I tried A lot of things :(. Unfortunatedly nothing worked. Thanks for the help anyway.